# Filter a list of CoreData items based on an array property using NSPredicate

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

## Context

I have a Core Data entity called 'Task'

'Task' has a relationship with another entity called 'Tag' : `@NSManaged public var tags: NSSet?`
This data is stored as:

```
public var tagsArray: [Tag] {
    let set = tags as? Set<Tag> ?? []

    return set.sorted {
        $0.wrappedTagTitle < $1.wrappedTagTitle
    }
}
```

I am trying to filter a list of tasks on the basis if they contain a certain tag, i.e. with a title of "School".

```
var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Task>

init(tagFilterName: String) {
    let tag = Tag()
    tag.title = tagFilterName
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Task>(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "tagsArray CONTAINS %@", tag))
}
```

This is initialised in the parent view:

```
FilteredScrollView(tagFilterName: "School")
```

(Excuse the haphazard code in the init, I am just trying to get across what I am trying to do.)

## Result

As it stands this crashes on runtime.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you're calling `Tag()` to create a new instance, which doesn't call the designated initializer. To create a new `Tag` you would need to use `Tag(context: NSManagedObjectContext)`. You're getting a crash because you're trying to use an object that wasn't properly initialized.

That's only part of the problem though. If you fix that, you'll fix the crash but you'll get zero results. The other problem is that you shouldn't be creating a new `Tag` for the fetch. Core Data predicates look for exact matches-- there's nothing like `Equatable`, and it won't look for some other `Tag` that has the same title. It's going to look for that exact tag. But since you just created that tag and since it's not connected to any tasks, you'll get zero results. The `CONTAINS` operator won't match anything since no `Task` contains the `Tag` you just created.

To match on a property value on through a relationship-- in this case, matching `Tag.title` via the `tags` relationship-- your predicate would look like

```
NSPredicate(format: "any tags.title = %@", tagFilterName)
```

When fetching `Task`, this asks for any `Task` where any member of the `tags` relationship has a value equal to `tagFilterName`.

Comment: In addition to Tom's points above, note that (for an SQLite store) CoreData will not recognise the computed property `tagsArray` when doing a fetch.  But you can use the underlying relationship, `tags`, instead: ie. "any tags.title == %@".

Comment: Whoops, I forgot that `tagsArray` was a computed property. Fixed and thanks for the catch.